# ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient in R - custom colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

Help needed please with `scale_fill_gradient()` in `ggplot2`. Consider this simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(3)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100, 0, 1), ncol = 10))

# turn from wide to long

dat2 <- dat %>%
  rownames_to_column("model_1") %>%
  gather(model_2, value, -model_1) %>%
  mutate(model_1 = model_1 %>% factor(levels = 1:10),
         model_2 = factor(gsub("V", "", model_2), levels = 1:10))

## plot data

ggplot(dat2, aes(model_1, model_2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "white")
```

What I'd like to do is to have custom shading rules. For example, something like:

- `value < 0.05`: bright yellow
- `value >= 0.05 & value < 0.15`: pale yellow
- `value >= 0.15`: white
- `is.na(value)`: white

Is there any easy way to do this please? I'm afraid I don't really follow the documentation for `scale_fill_gradient()`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try manually add color:

```
dat2 <- dat2 %>%
  mutate(
    my_color = case_when(
      value < 0.05 ~ "#FFFF00"  ,
      value >= 0.05 & value < 0.15 ~ "#FFFFCC",
      TRUE ~ "#FFFFFF"
    )
  )

ggplot(dat2, aes(model_1, model_2)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill = my_color)) + 
      geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2))) +
      scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]